# How to replacing a ByteToMessageDeocder in a safe way?

Tags: netty

I designed the following protocol.

| Header’s Length | Header | Content | Delimiter(end flag) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000101 | HELLO | json | ###end### |

The Client sends a message which contains “Header’s Length”,”Header”,”content”and “Delimiter”. It should be noted that the client will not send a complete message at once, the “Contend”field will be sent multiple times.when the client finish sending the Content field it will attach “###end###” at the end.The Server’s job is to get the “Header”field and the “Content” field.

The Business logic is to handle the “Header” and “Content”. So I need to get these from the bytebuf. The first thing that comes to my mind is using a decoder extends [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) to get “Header”.When I get the first decoded frame ,namely the “Header”, i will change the pineline by replacing the decoder to another.In the end,I'll use the new handler to deal with leftover message.

I tried to overwrite LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder's decode() method according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530518/10397315). But it seems to be an infeasible method. When the decoder is removed from the pipeline,client is still sending messages.so what happen to these message? Will these messages be dropped？

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol format is a bit more complicated than just a simple build in decoder. This means you have to write your own decoder.

Looking a your format, we can identity the following states:

- Read header length: read exactly 4 bytes
- Read header: Read for the X amount of from last value
- Read message until you see delimiter

Implementing a state switch like this is not too difficulty when using a `ReplayingDecoder`.

For example:

```java
enum FrameDecoderState {
    FRAME_HEADER_LENGTH,
    FRAME_HEADER,
    FRAME_BODY
}

public class FrameDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<FrameDecoderState> {
    private int headerLength;
    private ByteBuf header;
    private int detectedMessageLength;
    private final ByteBuf delimiter;

    public FrameDecoder(ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(FRAME_HEADER_LENGTH);
        this.delimiter = Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter, "delimiter");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelUnregistered(ctx);
        if (header != null) {
            header.release();
        }
        delimiter.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        switch(this.state()) {
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Shouldn't reach here.");
            case FRAME_HEADER_LENGTH:
                headerLength = buf.readInt();
                checkpoint(FRAME_HEADER);
            case FRAME_HEADER:
                header = buf.readBytes(headerLength);
                detectedMessageLength = 0;
                checkpoint(FRAME_BODY);
            case FRAME_BODY:
                int bodyStart = buf.readerIndex();
                while(true) {
                    if (findDelimiter(bodyStart + detectedMessageLength, buf)) {
                        out.add(new FrameDecoderFrame(header, buf.readBytes(detectedMessageLength)));
                        buf.readerIndex(bodyStart + detectedMessageLength + delimiter.capacity());
                        checkpoint(FRAME_HEADER_LENGTH);
                        break;
                    }
                    detectedMessageLength++;
                }
        }
    }

    private boolean findDelimiter(int bufIndex, ByteBuf buf) {
        for (int delimiterIndex = 0; delimiterIndex < delimiter.capacity(); delimiterIndex++) {
            if (buf.getByte(bufIndex) != delimiter.getByte(delimiterIndex)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                bufIndex++;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class FrameDecoderFrame extends AbstractReferenceCounted {
    private final ByteBuf header;
    private final ByteBuf body;

    public FrameDecoderFrame(ByteBuf header, ByteBuf body) {
        this.header = header;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public ByteBuf getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public ByteBuf getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.header);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.body);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final FrameDecoderFrame other = (FrameDecoderFrame) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.header, other.header)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.body, other.body)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FrameDecoderFrame{" + "header=" + header + ", body=" + body + '}';
    }

    @Override
    protected void deallocate() {
        header.release();
        body.release();
    }

    @Override
    public FrameDecoderFrame touch(Object o) {
        header.touch(o);
        body.touch(o);
        return this;
    }
}
```

After writing such an encoding make sure to test it, including with the cases there is partial data, or when there are multiple frames in the same message, for example:

```java
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
public void testBasic() {
    var channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new FrameDecoder(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("###end###".getBytes(US_ASCII))));

    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.buffer().writeInt(4));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("te".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("st{\"test\":".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("true}".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("###".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("end".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("###".getBytes(US_ASCII)).writeInt(0).writeBytes("[]###end###".getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    assertEquals(
        new FrameDecoderFrame(
            Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("test".getBytes(US_ASCII)),
            Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("{\"test\":true}".getBytes(US_ASCII))
        ),
        channel.readInbound()
    );
    assertEquals(
        new FrameDecoderFrame(
            Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER,
            Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("[]".getBytes(US_ASCII))
        ),
        channel.readInbound()
    );
    assertNull(channel.readInbound());
}
```